# How to get parameter name with C#

Tags: c#

How can we get parameter name called by a method in C#?

Example:

```
public static void PrintList (List<string> list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}

PrintList(oxygenList);
```

I need the method to print:

> oxygenList

Thanks.

Comment: [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Comment: You mean you want to print "oxygenList"? Then you need to pass this name as additional parameter to the `PrintList` method. Or do you want to print "list"?

Comment: I want to print oxygenlist, the argument passed to method

Answer (score 5):

If you're using C# 10 or later, you can use the new [`CallerArgumentExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/caller-argument-expression) attribute to achieve this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> oxygenList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
        PrintList(oxygenList);
    }

    public static void PrintList(List<string> list, [CallerArgumentExpression("list")] string? name = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Argument name = " + name); // Prints "Argument name = oxygenList
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

However, note that this gives the *expression* used when calling the method - so if you call it with this code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    PrintList(getOxygenList());
}

public static List<string> getOxygenList()
{
    return new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
}
```

the value passed as `name` will be "getOxygenList()".

It has to work like this because an expression can be used for the parameter - it's not restricted to a simple variable name.

Comment: which using I have to use to get "CallerArgumentExpression" work?

Comment: @Diego The code above should work, but it's documented as being a C#10 feature, so you'll need a recent Visual Studio and .net 5.0 or later (I think). The main using is `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`. Here's a .net Fiddle that shows it working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HpJl3D

Comment: @Diego: Why you need that information at all? If it's important, pass it to the method as additional argument. Maybe you want to use an enum instead of a string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would use this information inside a method that print a list, and preceding printing of list by naming it. I wish it's clear my object now. Example: This is the list: "myList" ..... List print....   Thanks.

Comment: @Diege: Normally you would simply add a method parameter `string name`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof(list));
```

See more: [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Update:
This is still not clear for me what do You want to achieve but the easiest way would be:

```
public static void PrintList (List<string> list, string nameOfList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameOfList);
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}

PrintList(oxygenList, nameof(oxygenList));
```

You may also create a bit cleaner extension method, like this:

```
public static class ListPrinter
{
    public static void PrintListWithName(this List<string> list, string nameOfList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameOfList);
        list.ForEach(element => Console.WriteLine(element));
    }
}
```

called like this:

```
oxygenList.PrintListWithName(nameof(oxygenList));
```

Comment: I guess he wants the name `oxygenList` not `list`

Comment: @TimSchmelter That may be one posibility, but OP did not add what they wanted to see printed. They could either want displayed `list` or `oxygenList`...

Comment: I want oxygen list not list, thanks anyway

Comment: You should have added that information to your question, because without that information both answers you got are valid (each one addressing one of the options). If you want displayed `oxygenList` you should check [Matthew Watson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71006628/2265446)

Comment: @Pawel Because of the recent edit of the question, you may want to check if this answer is still valid after the edit.

Comment: Thank You @Cleptus. I wasn't able to do that earlier.